# Compatibilidade NoSql .Net

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, nosql

Gostaria de saber se existe algum banco Nosql que seja mais fácil de trabalhar com .Net (que seja fácil de integrar, manipular, criar as entidades pelo entity framework se possível, etc).

Se puderem dar detalhes de framework, dll, etc, para integrar com .Net (Visual Studio)

Não sei se já existe alguma pergunta desse tipo aqui no fórum.

Comment: creio não ser possível... até porque não faz sentido você querer usar um banco Nosql e fazer anotações em tabelas / propriedades que tendem a ser relacionais.

Comment: No EF Core vai poder https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar MongoDB com esses requisitos. Você não tem o conceito de tabelas, mas sim de Collections.
No próprio site oficial do MongoDb existe um tutorial de como fazer essa conexão:
[MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/)

Esse post também é muito interessante: [.Net + MongoDB](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core)

Você pode baixar o pacote do MongoDB direto do Nuget no Visual Studio.